# Get a controller name from within the conroller class from within the Sub New() constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, controller

I am trying to make it generic - something like  ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") but the problem is that most of the object are not instantiated at this point so I don't know how to get the controller name at this particular point.

```
Public Class TestMeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Sub New()

      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ControllerNameWithSpaces") = Utilities.AddSpaceToControllerNameBeforeEachUpperCase("Here I want to pass a name of the controller")

'I could Easily just hard code "TestMe" or "TestMe" And would get back "Test Me" and that would solve it but that is not the point. 

    End Sub

    Function Index() As ActionResult
      Return View()
    End Function

End Class
```

So the question is:

In the controller's Sub New() constructor - is there some way to get a hold of the current class (controllerName)) at this particular moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor (in C#) you can get the class name:

```
this.GetType().Name
```

If memory serves, in VB.Net, that would be:

```
Me.GetType().Name '???
```

In an action you can get the controller name in C# from the RouteData:

```
RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

Comment: should just be `RouteData.Values("controller")` in vb

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure of his Sub New() syntax. On second look, that must be the constructor, in which case this won't work, as the RouteData hasn't been built yet. You can do it within an action, though.

Comment: this.GetType().Name - 100% Correct I should have thought of it as just a class. Thank you for answering the question, sir!

Comment: Me.GetType().Name in VB.NET for those who needs it